# Show product options as a grid/matrix in product detail page

Tags: php, magento

I have to develop a feature in product details page as shown in the screenshot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7ntplkxf3qrvo8/details.png

The `options` in the *grid* are selectable and change according to paper or color selected.
What i don't understand is should they be configurable options or custom options.

And if anyone know a good `magento` `extension` to make a *grid* like (*matrix*) of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that it's viable on Magento, BUT, you can create a custom JS function with an predesigned table programming for example:

```
1 day = price + 15%
3 day = price + 7%
6 day = price
```

Does that make cence, if this approach is not clear for you send me message and i'll try to help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Magento tire prices for this kind of stuff. Custom options are not helpful for this, because for every tireprice the additional costs are different.

Problem is, tire prices of simple products are not added to configurable products.
Maybe the [simple configurable products extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) will be helpful for this.

You can also try an approach with using grouped product to avoid this.